# Num_workers > 0 creates a memory error in SLURM?

Tags: python, pytorch, slurm

I'm trying to run my code on a SLURM cluster with the following configuration - 1 node, 2 Nvidia 1080Ti GPUs, 8 CPUs and 8GBs of RAM per CPU.

I'm implementing ResNeXt, with a dataset that contains about 1million 32x32 images. When I try running this code with `torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder` and `num_workers` = 4-8, it throws an "exceeded virtual memory" error by requesting for 341GB of data! That seems a little absurd. This error is thrown at the first trainLoader loop as it is preparing the first batch for the code.

Initially, I assumed this was an error with my program, but my program works just fine with `num_workers` = 8 on Google Colab. My program only works when I set `num_workers` = 0. At `num_workers` = 2, it works for two epochs before throwing the same error.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

#SBATCH --partition=gpu
#SBATCH --nodelist=compute-2-3
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=16
#SBATCH --time=24:00:00
#SBATCH --mem=100000M
#SBATCH --job-name="test"
#SBATCH --output=srun_output.out
#SBATCH --mail-user=vsanil@andrew.cmu.edu
#SBATCH --mail-type=FAIL
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:2

srun python -u next.py > srun_output.out
```

Comment: Can you start a bash shell and run `df -h` to check the size of `/dev/shm`? This is the RAM disk where pytorch's `DataLoader` class stages data loaded from from other threads before putting collating it. Also try playing with the `pin_memory` argument.

Comment: Err... you say that you have 8CPUs with 8GiB each, so 64GiB per node. And in the SLURM script you are asking for 100000MiB (roughly 100GiB). You don't have that much memory. SLURM should had not started the job because there is no machine that fulfills the requirements :-?

Comment: Ah, that was an oversight on my part, sorry! The node can support upto 128GB RAM, so 100GB of RAM is allocated without any issues.

Comment: @jodag I ran df -h, it says the size of /dev/shm is 48G when I allocate 64G to the program. That seems quite a lot of RAM available for my program to run!

Comment: Yup thats probably sufficient unless your using very large data samples or batch size.

Comment: @jodag To clarify about my dataset, it contains 1.5million 32x32, about 5GB in size, taken in batches of 128 into my network. I also tried playing around with `pin_memory` argument, it made no difference.